# How to use JavaScript in Velocity file from Webwork1 module?

Tags: javascript, html, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I have an Atlassian SDK webwork1 module with its view:

```
  <webwork1 key="ai-config" name="AI Config" i18n-name-key="ai-config.name"> 
    <description key="ai-config.description">The AI Config Plugin</description>  
    <actions> 
      <action name="com.softgile.jira.webwork.AIConfigAction" alias="AIConfigAction">
        <view name="success">/templates/ai-config/success.vm</view> 
      </action> 
    </actions> 
  </webwork1>
```

In the view I have several forms:

```
<form class="aui" id="configForm" method="post" action="AIConfigAction!saveIp.jspa">

...

</form>

<form class="aui" id="serviceName" method="post" action="AIConfigAction!saveService.jspa">

...

</form>
```

Also I have a button there, which is controlled with JS:

```
<div class="field-group">
    <label for="authenticate">
        <span class="aui-icon aui-icon-large aui-iconfont-app-access">Insert meaningful text here for accessibility</span>
    </label>
    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="aui-button aui-button-primary" id="authenticate">Authenticate</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

In JS file I have something like this:

```
AJS.toInit(function(){

    AJS.$(document).on('click', '#authenticate', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("authenticate");
    });


});
```

Both forms work okay, and JS works when I click the button. But JS stops working when I submit one of the forms, it works only before submitting forms. I see that URL is changing from `AIConfigAction.jspa` to `AIConfigAction!saveService.jspa` and in that case JS not working. How can I make JS work?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution myself. So, the problem in my case was that I was including web-resources  inside doExecute() method of the Webwork. That is why after calling other methods like doSave() web-resources stopped working.

Solution - move web-resources inclusion to Webwork constructor:

```
@Inject
public AIConfigAction(WebResourceManager webResourceManager) {

webResourceManager.requireResourcesForContext("myPlugin");

}
```